# R reduce two columns to table (crosstabulation)

Tags: r, crosstab

I think table does this, but I can't figure out how.

If I have a data frame with multiple columns:

- Student ID,
- Class designator,
- Mid Term results,
- End Term results

and both Mid Term results and End Term results have a fixed number of options, e.g. A,B,C

**How do I reduce this to a 3x3 matrix of Mid Term vs End Term?**

i.e. 20 Mid Terms of A resulted in End Terms  15, 4, 1 and Mid Terms of B resulted in etc.

Comment: Please include a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is called a table or [tag:crosstab]. You want a table/crosstabulation of MidTerm and EndTerm

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the `table` function:

```
table(dat$Midterm, dat$Endterm)
#     A B C
#   A 3 2 0
#   B 1 2 1
#   C 0 1 0
```

Here, the rows are the midterm grade and the columns are the endterm grade. You could also generate one table per class:

```
lapply(split(dat, dat$Class), function(x) table(x$Midterm, x$Endterm))
# $`1`
#    
#     A B C
#   A 2 1 0
#   B 0 0 1
#   C 0 1 0
# 
# $`2`
#    
#     A B C
#   A 1 1 0
#   B 1 2 0
#   C 0 0 0
```

Data:

```
set.seed(144)
(dat <- data.frame(StudentID=sample(1:1000, 10), Class=sample(1:2, 10, replace=TRUE), Midterm=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10, replace=TRUE), Endterm=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10, replace=TRUE)))
#    StudentID Class Midterm Endterm
# 1         50     2       A       B
# 2        707     1       A       A
# 3        726     2       B       A
# 4        500     1       B       C
# 5        317     1       A       A
# 6        636     1       C       B
# 7         36     2       A       A
# 8        724     2       B       B
# 9         78     2       B       B
# 10       815     1       A       B
```

Comment: Thank you josilber, both for reformatting my question and for the answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Apparently I am still learning how StackOverFlow works as well as R, thanks also to Sathya and Deepend.